# Adyen validation 906 error

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I have a really nasty error that I don't understand in Adyen and it goes something like this:

```
  SoapFault: validation 906 Invalid Request: Original pspReference is invalid for this environment!
```

I have checked the entire script, from top to bottom and back and the pspReference is the same throughout the entire system. So that number does not change.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is the deal:

The above error means that the pspReference number that you are sending falls in one of this 2 situations:

1. Either the pspReference number is from the test platform but is sent to the live one
2. Or the pspReference is from live and sent to test

Either way, in this case, you have to check for the link on which you send the collected form information.

Hope it helps,

Keep on coding!

Ares.